# When did Sylar gain a flying ability?

Tags: heroes

Towards the end of season 4 of Heroes, after Sylar's desire is revealed to be Claire (from the tattoo of her on his arm), we see him floating outside her dorm window (very end of episode 13: Let It Bleed), watching her.

Where did Sylar get a flying ability from?

He posed as Nathan for a while but all the abilities "Nathan" was manifesting were Sylar's, since it was Sylar's body.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sylar acquired Nathan's flying ability during the fight with Nathan in season 3 episode 25, "An Invisible Thread."  You can see Sylar floating through a window in the image below.  He had just thrown Nathan through the window onto a piano.

[image: Sylar floats into the room]

Matt Parkman stuffed Nathan's memories into Sylar's body later in that episode, but the flying ability had already been acquired by then.

Comment: +1 for the screen-grab and exact episode reference. It never showed Sylar actually taking the ability & he rarely used it.

Answer (score 3):

He acquired it from Nathan along with most of Nathan's memories.

By the end of the series, Sylar has finally managed to figure out how to acquire the abilities of other mutants without killing them. He takes Elle's electricity ability, for example, and several others, while leaving them alive.

When Sylar has Nathan in captivity and is absorbing his memories (using the ability he took from Bridget Bailey -- absorbing the past history of Nathan's things), he also acquires Nathan's flight ability. Sylar is shown to use the flight ability at least once *before* Nathan actually dies.

Comment: I think I need to re-watch season 3, I thought Matt pushed all of Nathan's memories into Sylar after Sylar killed Nathan?

Comment: Sylar was trying to steal Nathan's memories to get himself closer to the President; IIRC what Matt did was to simply make the Nathan personality take control over Sylar's body.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much all Matt did.  Angela Petrelli even mentions that the ability to see the history of an object will fill in the gaps in Sylar/Nathan's memory.